# How can I access option value passed by serverless cli in serverless.ts?

Tags: typescript, yaml, serverless

While I using serverless framework using serverless.ts for setting, I got a question.

I can pass the value on serverless cli like this

```
serverless offline --stage prod
```

In serverless.yml, we can access this value by `${self:provider.stage}`
But I cannot access it on serverless.ts.
Of course, I know it can replaced to constant variable and don't pass the value on cli.
But I worder that I can never access passed value on serverless.ts.
Is there any way???

Answer (score 4):

*TL;DR*: my workaround was to use the function exported in `serverless/lib/utils/resolveCliInput`.

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but if your question is how to access the values passed to serverless CLI from within `serverless.(ts|js)` then I have a workaround.

I had this problem and I couldn't find any solution for it after googling for some time, so I started to dig in the `serverless` source code. I've noticed this file `serverless/lib/utils/resolveCliInput` that exports a single function that resolves input arguments.

To be honest, I don't know whether we can rely on this function in future versions of the framework (I've tested with version 2.8.0), but here is a working code example:

```
import resolveCliInput from 'serverless/lib/utils/resolveCliInput';
const { commands, options } = resolveCliInput(process.argv.slice(2));
const stage = options.s ?? options.stage ?? 'dev';
```

Of course we can use some library for parsing `process.argv` such as [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) or even parse the args in our code.

Comment: Te cliInput change to 

`import resolveCliInput = require("serverless/lib/cli/resolve-input");`

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct value,
`${self:provider.stage}` refer to the value inside of the `provider` key in your configure file (`self.provider`):

```
const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
  service: 'hexagonal-serverless-workshop',
  frameworkVersion: '3',
  plugins: ['serverless-esbuild'],
  provider: { // <--- HERE
    name: 'aws',
    runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
    stage: 'dev',
    httpApi: {
      cors: true,
    },
    apiGateway: {
      minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
      shouldStartNameWithService: true,
    },
    environment: {
      AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: '1',
      NODE_OPTIONS: '--enable-source-maps --stack-trace-limit=1000',
    },
  },
 ...
}
```

The `--stage prod` here is available in the `${opt:stage}`.

For getting the stage, I recommend using a conditional value `${opt:stage, self:provider.stage, 'dev'}`

This will check the value stage from the option, if it's not set will use the value defined in the configuration, and if it's not set, will set it as `dev`.

You can have more detailed information here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables